# Creating a stream from scratch or from an Iterator

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I can't figure out a good way to create a [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from scratch. Suppose for instance (note, the code below is just an example for the sake of the discussion) that I have

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(re).matcher(input);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find())
    matches.add(m.group());
```

and want to leverage the stream API. I would like to do someting like

```
List<String> matches = Stream.of(() -> m.find(), () -> m.group())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where `() -> m.find()` is a function telling if there are more elements, and `() -> m.group()` is a function to provide the next element.

It's easy to create an `Iterator` for instance:

```
class MatchIterator implements Iterator<String> {
    Matcher m;
    boolean hasNext;
    public MatchIterator(Matcher m) {
        this.m = m;
        hasNext = m.find();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return hasNext;
    }
    @Override
    public String next() {
        String next = m.group();
        hasNext = m.find();
        return next;
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out an easy way of creating a stream out of an iterator either.

---

Edit: I realize I can create an `Iterable` that creates `MatchIterator`s (and then use `StreamSupport`/`Spliterator`) but that requires me to be able to iterate over the source multiple times, so it's still not a universal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a `Stream`, you need a `Spliterator`.  Then you make a `Stream` with `StreamSupport.stream()`.  (This is what all the collections do.)

If you already have an `Iterable`, you can get a `Spliterator` from its `spliterator()` method (though you might want to write a better one; the default is weak).

If you have an `Iterator`, you can turn it into a `Spliterator` with `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(Iterator)`.  (Again, this gets you a spliterator, but not necessarily an optimal one.)

If you have neither, you can just write a `Spliterator`; it's generally easier than writing an `Iterator` (more methods to implement, but generally simpler because you don't have to duplicate logic between `next` and `hasNext`.)

Comment: Thanks Brian. The `Spliterators` class and the `spliteratorUnknownSize` was sort of the missing piece in my puzzle. The fact that `tryAdvance` should push the next value to a consumer was also a bit confusing when being used to implementing good old iterators. But I agree, it's arguably easier to implement a `Spliterator` once gotten used to this.

Answer (score 2):

If you can reformulate your regular expression to specify the boundaries rather than the matches you might have a look at [`Pattern.splitAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-). I didn’t find a similar solution for getting a stream of matches, so I made one which will follow at the end of this answer.

This solution will allow to create a `Stream<MatchResult>` rather than a `Stream<String>` as it is easy to `map` such a stream to the entire match using `.map(MatchResult::group)` but offers a greater flexibility. See the following use case:

```
String testcase="first \"second item\" third";
MatchSpliterator.stream("\"([^\"]+)\"|\\S+", testcase)
    .map(r->Optional.ofNullable(r.group(1)).orElseGet(r::group))
    .forEach(s->System.out.println("match: "+s));
```

prints

```
match: first
match: second item
match: third
```

Of course, collecting to a `List<String>` is straight-forward using `MatchSpliterator.stream(pattern, input) .map(MatchResult::group).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Implementation:

```
public class MatchSpliterator implements Spliterator<MatchResult> {

    public static Stream<MatchResult> stream(String pattern, CharSequence input) {
        return stream(Pattern.compile(pattern), input);
    }
    public static Stream<MatchResult> stream(Pattern p, CharSequence input) {
        return stream(p.matcher(input));
    }
    public static Stream<MatchResult> stream(Matcher matcher) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(new MatchSpliterator(matcher), false);
    }
    private final Matcher matcher;

    private MatchSpliterator(Matcher m) {
        matcher=m;
    }
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super MatchResult> action) {
        if(matcher.find()) {
            action.accept(matcher.toMatchResult());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public Spliterator<MatchResult> trySplit() {
        return null;
    }
    public long estimateSize() {
        return Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    public int characteristics() {
        return NONNULL|ORDERED;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really strange that there is no simple abstract stream implementation with abstract methods similar to an ordinary Iterator. It seems like hasNext/next would be sufficient to implement a rudimentary stream.

Comment: Actually I find `tryAdvance` much more convenient for use cases like this as the logic is contained in one method rather than being spread over two methods and the constructor. Besides the additional factory methods I added for easier use, there are only three small methods needed for implementing a `Spliterator`. I don’t think that this is more complicated than implementing an `Iterator`. Note that you can [create a `Spliterator` from an `Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.html#spliteratorUnknownSize-java.util.Iterator-int-)…

Comment: Ah, interesting points. I wasn't aware of the spliteratorUnknownSize method!